# Partition overwrite in hive

Tags: hive

I have table structure like date_created , value created in hive with partition column as date_created. 
Data in the table as of now is

```
Date_created , value
Jan,            a
Jan,            b
Jan,            c
```

Now I need to load new data like

```
Date_created, value
Feb ,         a
Feb ,         b
Jan ,         z
```

When this data is loaded in hive , how it will be ?
If this was a RDBMS table it was a simple insert. But in hive how to get it appended?
Because Jan partition be overwritten with `Jan,z` value.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE PARTITION (date_created)` will overwrite data.

`INSERT INTO TABLE PARTITION (date_created)` will append data.

See docs here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries